# Convert date to timestap in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, mktime

I have tried various answers that I found in SO but still I can't manage to make a date into timestamp and I always get a wrong result.

I have tried:

```
$date = $this->loadTemplate('element'); //2014-02-27 15:03:00
list($year, $month, $day, $hour, $minute, $second) = split('[- :]', $date);
$timestamp = mktime((int) $hour, (int) $minute,(int) $second,(int) $month,(int) $day,(int) $year);
echo date("r", $timestamp);
```

And the result I'm getting is:

```
Wed, 02 Dec 2026 00:00:00 -0700
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT**

---

It turned out that the problem was a `newline` that was generated by `$date`. I stripped the string from `newlines` and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of [`mktime`](http://php.net/mktime) how about [`strtotime`](https://www.php.net/strtotime)? Seems easier.

```
$date = '2014-02-27 15:03:00';
echo date("r", strtotime($date));

// Outputs Thu, 27 Feb 2014 15:03:00 +0000
```

**Infact**, if you have PHP 5.2 and above use [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php).

```
$date = new \DateTime('2014-02-27 15:03:00');
echo $date->format("r");

// Outputs Thu, 27 Feb 2014 15:03:00 +0000
```

Here is the [ideone](https://ideone.com/KzUOIe) to show it.

Comment: I have tried it and with `strtotime` I'm getting "Wed, 31 Dec 1969 17:00:00 -0700", which is still not the correct timestamp.

Comment: Then your problem lies within `$this->loadTemplate('element');` as I am getting the correct date you mentioned here `//2014-02-27 15:03:00`. @otinanai

Comment: this is the exact output I'm getting from `$this->loadTemplate('element');`. I don't think this variable (string) hides anything strange.

Comment: If `$this->loadTemplate('element');` outputs `2014-02-27 15:03:00` like you put in your initial code example then the above code **will** work. Try casting it to a string first? `(string) $this->loadTemplate('element');`.

Comment: It turned out that the problem was a `newline` that it was generated. You gave me a very good clue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
$date = $this->loadTemplate('element'); //2014-02-27 15:03:00
list($year, $month, $day, $hour, $minute, $second) = split('[- :]', $date);
$timestamp = mktime($hour, $minute,$second,$month,$day,$year);
echo date("r", $timestamp);
```

your mktime is in the wrong order see above

Comment: I know! you're right but I posted my desperate attempt after testing randomly the properties. It turned out that the problem was a `newline` that was generated by `$date`.